# I have a elasticsearch index a field called "authority" which has multiple string value i want the last value after last comma?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, devtools, elk

`elasticsearch` index name is `data1`
the `@authority` field sometimes contain multiple value or single value

```
"@authority": [
"stelar",
"chrish",
"leona",
"micky",
"somany",
"peter",
"nitra"]
```

I want to retrieve the authority name:

condition 1. when it contains multiple value it should retrive the value after the last comma

condition 2. if it contains single value it returns the value as it is
(i want to write a script and show the value in another field like "last_@authority").

My code but its failed.

I want to show the last_authority name in my `elasticsearch` index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ruby` filter like this:

```rb
filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      authority = event.get("@authority")
      if authority.is_a? String
        event.set("some_field", authority)
      else
        event.set("some_field", authority.last())
      end
    '
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain a little more about what the filter does